# High load in Java WatchService

Tags: java, bash, watchservice

I have a Java WatchService registered to check if a file is modified. Everything works fine if you use a file viewer like Sublime or Notepad. But if I try to edit my file (in this case a config.properties file) with bash file viewer like vim on the server, the while loop is executed permanently and thus putting a high load on the system with following output:

```
2016-11-28 15:17:38.031 [INFO ] [Thread-7] PropertyReader pollPropertyFileModification - while (true)
2016-11-28 15:17:38.031 [INFO ] [Thread-7] PropertyReader pollPropertyFileModification - while (true)
2016-11-28 15:17:38.031 [INFO ] [Thread-7] PropertyReader pollPropertyFileModification - while (true)
```

Is this a bug or am I using WatchService incorrectly? Here is my code:

```
    private void pollPropertyFileModification() {
        logger.debug("entry");

        final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty(Constants.CONFIG_FILE));
        logger.debug("Filename: {}", path.getFileName());
        logger.debug("Parent Path: {}", path.getParent());

        try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            path.getParent().register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
//            final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            while (true) {
                logger.info("while (true)");
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    // we only register "ENTRY_MODIFY" so the context is always a Path.
                    final Path filename = (Path) event.context();
                    logger.info("Filename: {}", filename);

                    if (filename.endsWith(path.getFileName())) {
                        logger.info("{} has changed", filename);
                    }
                }

                // reset the key
                if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                    logger.info("Key has been unregistered");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("IOException", ex);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException", ex);
        }

        logger.debug("exit");
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
As @Ironcache pointed out, the `watchService.take();` call is in the wrong place and has to be put inside the loop

```
    private void pollPropertyFileModification() {
        logger.debug("entry");

        final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty(Constants.CONFIG_FILE));
        logger.debug("Filename: {}", path.getFileName());
        logger.debug("Parent Path: {}", path.getParent());

        try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            path.getParent().register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

            while (true) {
                logger.info("while (true)");

                final WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    // we only register "ENTRY_MODIFY" so the context is always a Path.
                    final Path filename = (Path) event.context();
                    logger.info("Filename: {}", filename);

                    if (filename.endsWith(path.getFileName())) {
                        logger.info("{} has changed", filename);
                    }
                }

                // reset the key
                if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                    logger.info("Key has been unregistered");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("IOException", ex);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.error("InterruptedException", ex);
        }

        logger.debug("exit");
    }
```

Comment: The `take()` method of `WatchService` is the blocking call here.  If structuring it as in your code, it needs to be **within** your `while (true)` loop.  Otherwise, you'll just keep looping over and over on the same key (leading to a fruitless infinite loop).

Comment: This seems to solve the issue. I will have a further look on it, thank you!